# NodeJS and Class limitations

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am wondering if there is a way to handle the following scenarios in a CLASS in NodeJs. I have a class lets call it contact which has a bunch of string fields but also has for example an array of email class. How can i specify in JavaScript that a value should be actually an Array of another class since i cant specify data type in JavaScript. Also how can i restrict the value in a field in a class, for example my email class has a field called type which can either be "home|work|other"

Comment: Use typescript if you want type-safety in your JS. Alternatively, using getters and setters instead of exposing the array directly would allow you to do something like `addEmail(email) { if (!email instanceof Email) { throw. . .} }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Javascript is not going to give you static typing, since you're using Node and have some control over which version you are using you do have some other options. You can use a Proxy. If your email array is a proxy, you can control the setter and only allow what you want to be added. For example (not sure this snippet will run in all browsers):

```js
class Email {
  constructor(addr) {
    this.address = addr
  }
}

// proxy array to check for values on set
let emails = new Proxy([], {
  set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
    if (!(value instanceof Email)) {
      if (property != "length")
        console.log(`Array can only contain Email instances "${value}" is an incompatible type`)
      return true
    }
    target[property] = value;
    return true;
  }
});

// fails
emails.push(1)
console.log("current array:", emails)

// works
let e = new Email("test@example.com")
emails.push(e)
console.log("current array:", emails)

// fails
emails[0] = "test"
console.log("current array:", emails)
```

Comment: This is the answer I was waiting for but too lazy to type out an example.

Answer (score 2):

With "vanilla" Javascript, there is no specific way to tell an Array that it should be filled *only* with objects of another specific class. An array (and any other data structure, really) will accept basically whatever you throw it. This is perfectly valid JS (though in general you wouldn't often do something like this):

```
var array1 = [1, 'two', {three: true}, [4]];
```

If you are interested in type safety, you can check out something like [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), but it isn't required and can make things more complicated if you're just learning how the JS ecosystem works.

Comment: So if i go the TypeScript route, what would the best approach ? Write the Class in Typescript and then convert to JavaScript ? Since there is no support for those limitations in JavaScript how will that help much ?So the question is really how to take advantage of those TypeScript features without having to rewrite my hold NodeJS App

Comment: Without going too far into it, basically you write Typescript and then as part of your dev/build process it is transpiled into Javascript and executed by Node. Any errors such as attempting to put the wrong class into a typed array would be found during that transpilation process. Javascript itself remains blissfully ignorant.

Comment: That's what i thought, so basically i get the benefit at design / coding but not at run time. For example i cant prevent a user from using a value which is not part of the enum to pass to a class. To prevent this i have to go and check if it is a member of the enum and if not throw an error.

Comment: Correct - if you are accepting user data, or writing something that will eventually be distributed like a library, you need to validate any conditions (even so trivial as as "did you pass in a number") in your code. The language won't help you.

The JS ecosystem tends to be a bit accepting of these things. For example, a lot of times JS code just accepts whatever is passed in, and either it breaks things down the line or it doesn't. Whether this is good or bad is up to opinion.